# How to wait for HTTP Request Response + Confirm Dialogue PopUp + Angular 8

Tags: angular, async-await, httprequest, angular8

I have a requirement where I want to show the confirm popup message before redirecting to other page, where I am taking input from the user weather he want to leave with unsaved changes or not.

**What is happening!**

On browser confirm dialogue box come first then get the HTTP-Request response which is not correct.

**What should be!**

I want the HTTP Response get first and if condition satisfied then pop up the confirm dialogue message.

Here is the code sample I am using for my project.

**service.ts** file

```
 async IsUnSavedRosterExistsTwo() {
    console.log('async method called');
    const url = this.util.getBaseURL() + apiURLs.IsUnSavedRosterExists;
    const rr =  await this.http.get<boolean>(url).toPromise();
    console.log(rr);
    return rr;
  }
```

I have tried all the possible solution like subscribe, promise , pipe and all but nothing is work here.

**component.ts**

```
canDeactivate() {
    this.saveDownloadButton = false;
    // const IsUnSavedRosterExists = this.rosterService.IsUnSavedRosterExists();
    const IsUnSavedRosterExists = this.rosterService.IsUnSavedRosterExistsTwo();

    debugger;
    if (IsUnSavedRosterExists) {
      console.log('executing the code');
      return confirm('You have unsaved Employee Data. Do you wish to proceed without saving?');
    } else {
      this.saveDownloadButton = false;
    }
    return this.saveDownloadButton;
  }
```

**In Short, I want to wait for http-request response to come first and then execute if condition satisfies then pop up the confirm dialog box else redirect to other page.**

Do let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: `IsUnSavedRosterExistsTwo` is not returning anything? shouldn't it return the `rr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the **canDeactivate()** function into an *async* function and then you can *await* for the **this.rosterService.IsUnSavedRosterExistsTwo()** function to resolve before proceeding further. See the code below:

```js
async canDeactivate() {
    this.saveDownloadButton = false;
    const IsUnSavedRosterExists = await this.rosterService.IsUnSavedRosterExistsTwo();

    debugger;
    if (IsUnSavedRosterExists) {
      console.log('executing the code');
      return confirm('You have unsaved Employee Data. Do you wish to proceed without saving?');
    } else {
      this.saveDownloadButton = false;
    }
    return this.saveDownloadButton;
  }
```

Comment: For coming developers who are facing the same issue.. make sure you have maked your canDeactive method as a async method not any inner method which is calling to your service method....